# Has Hamas historically used protected civilian infrastructure as shields?

Tags: israel-hamas-war, hamas, gaza

Whether al-Shifa hospital etc. host Hamas weapons and tunnels is under current dispute (although the [videos of the under-hospital facilities](https://www.jdn.co.il/video/2083692/) keep pouring in).

However these are not new claims by the Israelis. For years and through multiple rounds of the conflict they've said Hamas deliberately hides among civilians and in populated, protected civilian infrastructure - mosques, schools, hospitals, ambulances, populated private residences, etc., making tactical use of Israeli reluctance to target them. And gaining international sympathy if Israel strikes anyway.

For example, a 2009 [post](https://www.terrorism-info.org.il/en/19103/) from The Meir Amit Intelligence and Terrorism Information Center:

> The many mosques in the Gaza Strip serve not only religious functions, but are also put to military use by Hamas and the other terrorist organizations. They are used to hide terrorist operatives, store weapons, as sites from which rockets and mortar shells are launched, sites for launching terrorist attacks and for training terrorist operatives.

Is there any verified evidence from before Oct. 7, 2023 that Hamas has used active, protected civilian infrastructure as military defense (shields)? Preferably from non-IDF sources (for more impartiality).

Comment: "hides in civilian infrastructure". This would be surprising how? Even Ukraine does that, in practically every city fight they did. The controversial part is doing it with many civilians still milling about.

Comment: @Fizz: Yeah, hiding in an empty apt. building is one thing, but in an ambulance and hospital and school is another, because there's an assumed protection from, and expected condemnation of, strikes on such facilities.

Comment: Related Q (but with a quote, I suggest you also add one here): https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56354/did-ukraine-regularly-place-some-of-their-military-assets-in-areas-populated-by

Comment: Thanks, and [here's](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56354/did-ukraine-regularly-place-some-of-their-military-assets-in-areas-populated-by) another related in Politics. The answers there can really answer this Q too.

Comment: I note that the quoted claim is specifically about mosques. The current answer is about mosques and "residential neighborhoods, cemeteries, schoolyards, and mosque courtyards", but the claim is being used to suggest hiding in *hospitals*. The latter is clearly a war-crime. The former is less clear (perhaps "probably a war crime"). So beware of conflating the two issues.

Comment: "Whether al-Shifa hospital etc. host Hamas weapons and tunnels is under current dispute" after the idfs video displaying the hostages in the hospital, it isn't anymore.

Comment: @TheAsh, updated per your point...

Comment: This claim in The Meir Amit Intelligence and Terrorism Information Center about isn't about "civilian infrastructure" it's about religious infrastructure. Presumably Hamas uses roads, and bridges -- seems indisputable.

Comment: In an attempt to salvage answer that doesn't address the claim, you've changed the claim so much it is no longer notable. At this point, it seems to be pushing propaganda rather than addressing a doubt.

Comment: @Oddthinking, this is surprising to me, because the question was modified after days of no change, and then if you recall it was only to pacify a specifically agenda-based critique along with a sarcastic answer (now deleted) backing it up. You yourself stated, at the , that the question was clear. But I adjusted it anyway. Now the question gets deleted?! This feels like being boxed into a corner and then knocked out. Assume some are thrilled about that but not great for impartial reputation...

Comment: @YouDontSay The question hasn't been deleted, it's been closed. Those are two different things. "the question was modified after days of no change" - which of your eleven edits are you referring to? The only period I can see where the question went through "days of no change" is the three days up until now.

Comment: @F1Krazy, correct. question was closed. Sarcastic agenda-based answer, however, was deleted. Which covers the reason for the main change in the question that lead to its closing. 9 minor edits, mostly updates. One major edit when question was attacked by one of the most agenda-pushing voices on this forum.

Comment: @Oddthinking, another point, the same voice who attacked the question in the now-deleted answer, seems to be still quite doubtful about the edited question.  From my perspective this is not about pushing propaganda at all. It's a query to see if there's verifiable non-IDF evidence to a claim by Israel that is continually doubted by many. Seems a quite valid question for this forum, that was ultimately a victim of the very propaganda you're trying to avoid.

Comment: @YouDontSay: So, to restate: I said the question is clear. You edited it to make it non-notable. I closed it.

Comment: @Oddthinking, got it. I'm assuming the notability concern was the "human shield" part. I revised the question to be closer to original, while still protecting it from answers like "The IDF also uses roads." Hope it can be reopened.

Comment: @Oddthinking, Awesome!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Yes they did.

I'm assuming here that the side that asks this question will not be interested of any evidence provided by the IDF or Israeli authorities, so all the evidence brought here are from non Israeli sources.

In addition to Lio Elbammalf's answer citing the AP interview of Ghazi Hamad, we have other evidence from witnesses, analysts and from the head of Hamas himself.

Two examples of direct witnesses:

- [Aishi Zidan, a Finish reporter, in 2014 reports](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmQpiUvS2PQ&t=20s&ab_channel=TundraTabloids) from the very same al-Shifa hospital that she was a witness to a Hamas rocket fire from the premises of the hospital or very close to it:

> In addition a rocket was launched, right in the back parking lot of hospital(Shifa) a rocket was launched, two o'clock in the morning. Really,it happened right in the area, the sound of it was really loud it's true that rockets are launched here from the Gaza side into Israel.

- [UNWRA admits](https://www.unrwa.org/newsroom/press-releases/unrwa-condemns-placement-rockets-second-time-one-its-schools) that rockets or other weapons were placed in one of its schools two times, in violation of international law:

> UNRWA CONDEMNS PLACEMENT OF ROCKETS, FOR A SECOND TIME, IN ONE OF ITS SCHOOLS
>
> Today, in the course of the regular inspection of its premises, UNRWA discovered rockets hidden in a vacant school in the Gaza Strip. As soon as the rockets were discovered, UNRWA staff were withdrawn from the premises, and so we are unable to confirm the precise number of rockets. The school is situated between two other UNRWA schools that currently each accommodate 1,500 internally displaced persons.
>
> UNRWA strongly and unequivocally condemns the group or groups responsible for this flagrant violation of the inviolability of its premises under international law.

Then there is a report by [NATO Strategic Communications Centre of Excellence](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategic_Communication_Center_of_Excellence_(NATO))(stratcomcoe) about [Hamas' use of human shields in Gaza during the period of 2008-2014](https://stratcomcoe.org/cuploads/pfiles/hamas_human_shields.pdf):

> Hamas’ most common uses of human shields include:
>
> - Firing rockets, artillery, and mortars from or in proximity to heavily populated civilian areas, often from or
>   near facilities which should be protected according to the Geneva Convention (e.g. schools, hospitals,
>   or mosques).
> - Locating military or security-related infrastructures such as HQs, bases, armouries, access routes,
>   lathes,
>   or defensive positions within or in proximity to civilian areas.
> - Protecting terrorists’ houses and military facilities, or rescuing terrorists who were besieged or
>   warned by the IDF.
> - Combating the IDF from or in proximity to residential and commercial areas, including using civilians for
>   intelligence gathering missions

And finally we have an admission from the head himself, in [this video posted to Twitter by the IDF](https://twitter.com/IDF/status/1401606703230197769?lang=en) from 2021 Yahya Sinwar himself admits that Hamas and other terrorist organizations have their headquarters located inside civilian buildings:

> The issue of military headquarters embedded in civilian populations posed a huge problem during the previous rounds of fire. We, and other [militant] functions, have initiated a gradual transfer operation, with the aim of relocating a significant number of military headquarters from within the civilian population. We have managed to move many headquarters [from within the civilian population], but it's necessary to move many more, with God's help we'll continue this work.
>
> We are paying attentions to this issue and have taken care to move a large portion of the headquarters mainly from the towers, residential buildings, and other places. We have successfully relocated many of these headquarters and Inshalla we'll complete this task.

He talks about moving them from the civilian population, but in doing so he admits that:

- There were many military headquarters imbedded in the civilian population.
- There were still many military headquarters imbedded in the civilian population when he gave the speech.
- The military headquarters weren't "just" in proximity to civilian buildings, but inside them "in towers, residential building, and other places".

Comment: You divide sources into Israeli and non-Israeli, which comes to mind that "Oh, so that's a fair answer." But in fact, this division is not fair. I divide it into 6 sets: Israeli sources (which include left and right), European sources (which include left and right), Western sources (which include left and right), West Bank Palestinian sources, Hamas sources and pro-Hamas sources.

Comment: You can add this link: https://www.timesofisrael.com/uk-doctor-who-worked-at-shifa-confirms-gaza-hospital-used-for-non-medical-purposes/  a testimony of a UK doctor who worked at Shifa, and saw evidence to Hamas presence.

Comment: @Erel Segal-Halevi: You can add this link: https://www.democracynow.org/2023/10/30/gaza_hospitals a testimony of a Norwegian doctor who worked at Shifa, and saw __NO evidence__ to Hamas presence. OR [BBC](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZPOoF4f_p4)

Comment: @C.F.G just because someone didn't see evidence doesn't mean that there wasn't. He or she just didn't see.

Comment: @TheAsh: We are not talking about a small gun inside a hospital. The claim is huge. Using the hospital as a military base. It is not something that no one can see. The BBC also confirmed that Israel is lying.

Comment: @C.F.G, if you look at the testimony of the UK doctor he doesn't say "Yes, I saw Hamas officials firing rockets". He said that there was a section of the Hospital where he was directly told to stay away, and it was heavily implied that this was used by Hamas. I never saw with my own eyes the IDF chief of stuff enter or leave the Kirya base, but I know he is located there because of the guards. In addition the Norwegian doctor never said he personally didn't see anything. And lastly, Israel's claim is that Hamas used the basements and tunnels below, not hang around in the Doctors break room.

Comment: @SIMEL: This does not mean that the hospital is used as a military defense (shield) as the question is being asked. Some users say something relevant, then attach to that valid answer some evidence unrelated to the question. This way of answering is not appropriate at all. (like the user that I replied to in the comment).

Comment: @C.F.G, the question asked did Hamas use civilian protected buildings for military use. There are clear evidence that they did. Including an admission by Sinwar. Specificly for the comment added, if there are evidence that the Hospital was used by Hamas (or other terrorist groups) for anything other than healing their sick and wounded, then yes, it also answers the question as it shows that Civilian protected complex was used for military purpose, this is appropriate and directly answers the question.

Comment: @C.F.G Europe is part of the West.

Comment: @Acccumulation: Yes, of course, but not all of its countries. But I do not see the connection between your comment and mine?

Answer (score 12):

#### Yes, Hamas, according to an interview between AP news and Ghazi Hamad, admitted to doing as such during the 2014 war:

[This article quotes Hamas as admitting to using civilian areas](https://apnews.com/article/lifestyle-middle-east-hamas-152644963f4249a7a21154446649910a)

> Two weeks after the end of the Gaza war, there is growing evidence that Hamas militants used residential areas as cover for launching rockets at Israel, at least at times. Even Hamas now admits “mistakes” were made.
>
> But Hamas says it had little choice in Gaza’s crowded urban landscape, took safeguards to keep people away from the fighting, and that a heavy-handed Israeli response is to blame for the deaths of hundreds of Palestinian civilians.
>
> Throughout the war, the Israeli air force compiled dozens of video clips showing alleged wrongdoing by Hamas, an Islamic militant group sworn to Israel’s destruction.
>
> These videos, many of them posted on YouTube, appear to show rockets flying out of residential neighborhoods, cemeteries, schoolyards and mosque courtyards. There are also images of weapons caches purportedly uncovered inside mosques, and tunnels allegedly used by militants to scurry between homes, mosques and buildings.

[Link to IDF video evidence of launches](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUrDAEgisXM) from within built up neighbourhoods - I can't identify any of those as necessarily schools or hospitals but certainly appear to be private residences

Comment: The question is about infrastructure, the admission was "Hamad told The Associated Press, offering the first acknowledgment by a Hamas official that, in some cases, **militants fired rockets from or near (200-300 yards) residential areas or civilian facilities.**" Near does not substantiate a claim to be "using". The United States has Air Force Bases that close to houses too, https://maps.app.goo.gl/yS6k2Z2mGzro7a3d9 Also the IDF is not at all reliable source on this matter, lol. If their statement wasn't made, they'd be facing war crimes.

Comment: @Lio Elbammalf: You're right, and this could be answer to [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82261/according-to-pro-palestinian-sources-does-hamas-indeed-embed-itself-into-civili) Politics Q.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: "From" seems like "using"...

Answer (score -2):

### Yes, there is.

[There's some testimony](https://hamodia.com/2023/11/19/foreign-doctors-relate-their-experiences-with-hamas-terrorists-at-shifa-hospital/) from doctors who've worked in al-Shifa hospital in the past. Here's an excerpt from a British doctor who worked there in 2020, interviewed by France24:

> “When I was first asked to work there [at Shifa], I was told there was a part of the hospital I was not to go near, and if I did, I’d be in danger of being shot,” he was said in the interview.
>
> “Was it explained to you why that was?” Makler asked the doctor.
>
> “No, but implicit was that it was being used for non-medical purposes,” the doctor replied.
>
> “And did you see anything non-medical, or did you buy the instruction and stay away?” Makler persisted.
>
> “I stayed away, but I saw a few dodgy-looking non-medical characters going in and out all the time,” The doctor replied. “It was a ward leading to a basement. As I said I didn’t go there, so I behaved myself.”
>
> “They would say there could be many other reasons that you would be told not to go to a particular area of a hospital. It’s not unusual,” Makler countered.
>
> “Well, I was welcome everywhere else, and as I say, the doctors and nurses there were very welcoming and very kind, and the hushed tones under which this was said were consistent with all the other hushed tones with which Hamas was discussed. You know, people were genuinely fearful,” the doctor explained. “I cannot emphasize too much the air of collective paranoia that existed there.”
>
> The doctor told Makler that if hospital staff were 10% frightened of possible Israeli airstrikes, they were 90% frightened of being persecuted by Hamas.

Not direct observational evidence, but strong indications there was common knowledge of Hamas presence in, and use of, al-Shifa hospital.

If you consider actual humans to be protected civilian infrastructure, there's this, too, in a [recent document](https://www.terrorism-info.org.il/en/hamas-use-of-the-civilian-population-as-human-shields-and-gazas-civilian-facilities-for-terrorism/) by the The Meir Amit Intelligence and Terrorism Information Center, (a separate post from the one referenced in the question, and posted after the question). This is admittedly a pro-Israel source, with lots of information provided by the IDF spokesman, which is not impartial. **Of note however is the following**:

> **Yahya al-Sinwar uses children as human shields**
>
> When Yahya al-Sinwar, head of the Hamas political bureau in the Gaza Strip, appeared at mass and public events in the Gaza Strip, he was always seen with children nearby. Apparently al-Sinwar, who knew his life was in danger when he appeared in public, also knew that when children were nearby, Israel would not try to kill him because of its ethic not to harm innocent children. For example, on October 1, 2022, Hamas held a mass rally in Gaza City whose theme was “al-Aqsa [Mosque] is in danger.” Al-Sinwar appeared at the rally with two young children at his side (Hamas website, October 1, 2022). On May 26, 2021, a few days after Operation Guardian of the Walls, Yahya al-Sinwar was seen walking the streets of Gaza under tight security. Wherever he was, children were seen close by (Maan, May 26, 2021).[image: Yahya Sinwar with children at Hamas rally]

[image: Yahya Sinwar with child at Hamas rally]
[image: Human (toddler) shields]

These photos are conspicuous in that there are almost no other toddlers in the pictures, other than in the immediate proximity of Yahya Sinwar. This man who knows he's a target. The IDF military spokesman has [said about him](https://matzav.com/report-yahya-sinwar-hamas-leader-is-in-khan-yunis/),

> Our job is to reach Sinwar and kill him.

A bunch more pictures are provided, demonstrating a pattern of someone who knows he's a target, shielding himself with toddlers when overground.

And this:

> **Confirmation of Hamas’ use of the population as human shields**
>
> The Gazans do not generally protest the use Hamas and other terrorist organizations make of them as human shields. However, an unusual statement confirming the fact was a post uploaded by a Gazan named Khalil Amar Abu Ibrahim. He criticized the terms of the distribution of financial aid to the families of shaheeds in the Gaza Strip on behalf of the al-Ansar Charitable Association, which excluded children under the age of 15 and residents over the age of 60. He wrote there were dozens of families who lost their children because PIJ terrorist operatives barricaded themselves in their buildings. He personally lost his three children in the same attack, and they had served as human shields to protect where “so-and-so” from the “resistance” was staying (Facebook page of the al-Ansar Charitable Association, June 2, 2023).

As stated in the MA Intelligence report, these pictures and quotes are both **drawn from non-IDF sources**.

To sum it up, we have evidence of Hamas strategically shielding themselves with 1) hospitals, 2) humans (toddlers), and 3) populated civilian residences.

Comment: I am totally confused here, it looks like he's at a parade or festival. So because Yahya al-Sinwar had a picture taken with children around him he's using children as human shields? I was solicited to join the US Army _almost_ every day from 11th and 12th Grade, they were literally station IN my high school: does this satisfy your same definition of "human shield"?

Comment: "children definitely qualify as civilian infrastructure" only if you're literally attacking at the point of which you have children in your vicinity, not if you're at a youth rally where kids have obviously toy guns (they have orange tips).

Comment: This is the most propagandistic answer I've ever seen on this whole network: the kids aren't a means to deter a military counter attack ("shield" in "human shield"). He's just attending a festival or public rally. Having children around you isn't using children as human **shields**. This isn't remotely correct. When a US Serviceman returns on active duty and goes to a July 4th parade, is he using children as human shields?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149787/discussion-on-answer-by-youdontsay-has-hamas-historically-used-civilian-infrastr); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Moved comments that were political posturing to chat. This is not about sides. It is about evidence. And this answer doesn't address the question.

Comment: Q adjusted, should be clear now how A addresses it.

Comment: I don't understand how this answer gets to sit. The claim/question is "making tactical use of Israeli reluctance to target them". This is a public event. No one is "making tactical use of Israeli reluctance". Unless you think at the public non-military event Israeli would target the government of Gaza had it have not been for children present...

Comment: The new edit with a doctor talking about al-Shifa is great evidence that there were *rumours* and the doctor heard them, but not very good evidence that there was any military base. It also seems very much to address the issue that the question said it *wasn't* about.

Comment: @Oddthinking, I agree, it's not direct observational evidence. I admitted as much in the answer. (This dialogue was in the answer for a while, but I moved it to the top to more directly address the question before moving to the more arguable evidence of "human" infrastructure.) 2. Can you clarify the second point please? ("It also seems very much to address the issue that the question said it wasn't about.") Thanks.

Comment: @EvanCarroll, YouDontSay: I created a whole chat for you two to go off with your political rants. Keep them out of the comments. No further warnings.

Comment: The second point is that the question basically stars "Al-Shifa's status is currently under dispute, but looking past that, what is the historical evidence of Hamas doing this elsewhere?" and the new edit says "Let's start by looking at Al-Shifa." You know that evidence is being disputed and investigated. Bringing up one piece of bad evidence about it while ignoring the rest isn't helping.

Comment: @Oddthinking, got it. I thought it would help in showing something *historical* (2019) about al-Shifa itself, as an example of historical use of protected infrastructure. The dispute is about current use, as in should the IDF do the raid on the claim of tunnels currently under the hospital. But I concede the point.