# Did Ukraine regularly place some of their military assets in areas populated by civilians?

Tags: military, ukraine, russo-ukrainian-war, international-law

Amnesty International [claims](https://www.amnesty.org/en/latest/news/2022/08/ukraine-ukrainian-fighting-tactics-endanger-civilians/):

> Ukrainian forces have put civilians in harm’s way by establishing bases and operating weapons systems in populated residential areas, including in schools and hospitals, as they repelled the Russian invasion that began in February, Amnesty International said today [August 4, 2022].
>
> Such tactics violate international humanitarian law and endanger civilians, as they turn civilian objects into military targets. The ensuing Russian strikes in populated areas have killed civilians and destroyed civilian infrastructure.
>
> “We have documented a pattern of Ukrainian forces putting civilians at risk and violating the laws of war when they operate in populated areas,” said Agnès Callamard, Amnesty International’s Secretary General.

Did Ukraine do what is claimed in the 1st para? Is it a pattern, as claimed in the final para of the quote?

Comment: Please no comments like "but Russia does worse, so the West has no choice but to choose the lesser evil". I'm well aware of such facts & arguments.

Comment: Zelensky himself said something like that, that Amnesty “shift[s] the responsibility from the aggressor to the victim”. OTOH Amnesty said they stand by their findings and  that “nothing we documented Ukrainian forces doing in any way justifies Russian violations”. https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/aug/07/amnesty-international-ukraine-military-report-civilians

Comment: Russia has again and again and again attacked civilian targets with no military anywhere nearby, so that question is quite irrelevant.

Comment: IMO Ukraine has accepted this indirectly. See [this DW report](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Llm39sMaqQs).